# Is there any linux in built application or any method to find the network usage(data usage) of the internet connection?

Tags: network-monitoring, bandwidth, traffic, user-data

Is there any linux in built application or any method to find the network usage(data usage) of the internet connection? I know there are many softwares that can be installed into os for this purpose. But I doubt there is a in-built linux tool for this purpose.

Comment: Pretty much every tool I know of is a separate userspace program, and hence come as different package that you need to install.  But what is your requirement? What difference would it make ? If its just for the lack of internet connection to install, you could always build it in the target machine from source, which you should anyway download from another machine. Complexity might vary.

Answer (score 2):

Isn't `gnome-system-monitor` capable of doing this? You can see in this image, the bottom portion of it shows the network history of your computer :

[image]

Comment: Oh, sorry, I overlooked that one. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try `sudo apt-get install mbmon xmbmon`

Or try other stuff like [here](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/bandwidth-monitoring-tools-for-ubuntu-users.html)

You can try look for GUI interface for all those text apps
I don't understand what you mean by *in-built linux tool*, uh

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there are no *inbuild applications* as such in the kernel. But there are *facilities* in the kernel to track/do everything. But doing it on your own will be a tedious task as you will need to do it with a C program. That is what the external applications are doing. Virtually every command you run, is a userspace application.

Link posted by Paul doesnt mention one useful software. If you would like to see which *application* or *process* is using the bandwidth, I recommend using `nethogs`. Get it with `sudo apt-get install nethogs`

Usage : `sudo nethogs -p eth0`. Replace eth0 with whatever interface you want to peek into, like wlan0 for wireless.

Comment: nethogs too is a simple cmd tool. But I found NTM great..!!!

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution finally I think.. Network tools is an inbuilt tool(as I think) which do the purpose well.
As well the System Monitor (inbuilt tool) too does great..!!!
If u want another tool NTM is great and it is not an in built tool.

You can install ntm with this command

```
sudo apt-get install ntm
```